# KeyDown Event fires faster then a camera movement can proccess, how to queue the event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a camera that I move left and right with the arrows or 'A' and 'D' keys, unfortunately the camera response time is slower than the key held options in the application. I would like to move the camera smoothly while pressing the arrows but the program is stuck when I do it because it's too much pressing for the camera to process.

How can I hold the key and reduce the big number of commands that the camera gets and can't handle?

Comment: Sounds like you need a debounce: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=debounce&oq=debounce&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1935j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

@Webnoob is wise ... i never knew they have a name.
You'll want to do something like :

```
private DateTime _lastValidKey;
private int delay;

private void SomePreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // follow line need tweaking to your liking and needs
    if (now - delay > lastValidKey){
         // update _lastValidKey and forward key
    }
    else {
        // return, ignoring the keys
    }

    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.Up:
            // do something
            break;
        case Key.Down:
            // do something
            break;
    }

}
```

basically ...you're filtering out extra keypresses

Comment: it looks good, and I have a doubt, where is `delay` initialized? Thank you

Comment: Up to you . Constructor, it can a constant, you also need to make `now-delay` be meaningful as one is a datetime and one is either a number that need to be converted to milliseconds for example, or a timespan ... up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a "time quantum" for user input processing. Let say we have some event (mouse, keyboard) that may cause lengthy processing in model and/or view. In simplest case we receive the keypress and process it immediately.

```
public void OnUserInput( )
{
    DoSomething( );
}

private void DoSomething( )
{
    // and here we do it
}
```

We may change this into:

```
public void OnUserInput( )
{
    // DoSomething( );
    StartTimedUpdate( );
}

private void DoSomething( )
{
    // and here we do it
}

DispatcherTimer m_timer = null;

private void StartTimedUpdate()
{
    if (m_timer == null)
    {
        m_timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        m_timer.Tick += TimedRefresh;
        m_timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        m_timer.Start();
    }
}

private void TimedRefresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (m_timer != null)
        m_timer.Stop();
    m_timer = null;

    DoSomething();
}
```

You may also record all received keystrokes in list and process them in timer event handler. The 100 ms delay is just an example.